# Floating Action Button icon image not showing after hide and show

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button

Hi i'm developing an android application with Floating Action Button.

At first time the FAB icon shows icon image. After when i hide and show the icon image will be blank when i click FAB icon

This is the code that is used to hide the FAB

```
   mainScrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                // previousScrollY this variable is define in your Activity or Fragment
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onScrollChanged: scrollview position " + mainScrollView.getScrollY() + " " +
                                previousScrollY + " " +
                                mainScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
                        if (mainScrollView.getScrollY() > previousScrollY) {
                            fab.hide();
                        } else if (mainScrollView.getScrollY() < previousScrollY) {
                            fab.show();
                        }
                        if (mainScrollView.getScrollY() >= mainScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()) {
                            previousScrollY = mainScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                        } else if (mainScrollView.getScrollY() < 0) {
                            previousScrollY = 0;
                        } else {
                            previousScrollY = mainScrollView.getScrollY();
                        }
                    }
                }, 200);
            }

        });
```

onscrolling down the FAB icon will hide and onScrolling up the FAB icon will show.

And this is the code for FAB setOnClicklistener

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);
                } else {
                    sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_filter);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the fab icon image that appear Before Scrolling and first time loading
[image: Before Scrolling and first time loading opening fab]

[image: Before Scrolling and first time loading closing Fab]

this is the image after scrolling and clicking.

[image: fab icon image after scrolling and clicking.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know it has been a long time since you posted this but I had the same problem. I solved it by doing a hide() and then a show() to the fab after clicking. (In my particular case I change the drawable in onClick. Doing hide() and show() after changing the drawable solved the issue).

Your code shall look like:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (sheetBehavior.getState() != BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_close);
                } else {
                    sheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                    fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_filter);
                }
                fab.hide();
                fab.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Did face the same issue with dependency `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`. Upgrading the version to `1.1.0-alpha3` fixed the issue.

Comment: You are right, upgrading the library fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. Only thing that could perhaps cause that behaviour in my opinion is the delay handler in your `onScrollChanged`. Please go to the declaration of your global FloatingActionButton`fab` and make it `static`. See if that helps.

PS: If it does not indeed help, try replacing your `fab.hide()` with `fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and `fab.show()` with `fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: try removing the `new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() ` from your `onScrollChanged`.

Comment: I have already checked that.. i put the handler because of the FAB icon hide & show become awkward when it scrolls.

Comment: **VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)** this is the error when i try to set visibility on *FAB*.

Comment: As @Nishant pointed out is a library bug.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663687/5482999

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); && fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

insted of this

```
fab.show(); &&  fab.hide();
```

Comment: This generates an error: VisibilityAwareImageButton.setVisibility can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)

Comment: fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) try this

Comment: setVisibility generates an error. The only working workaround is the one with hide/show.

Comment: now, only one way take one parent layout and set visibility to that parent layout instand of action button.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by call function hide and show again in onCreateView

```
fab.hide();
fab.show();
```